# Regex to identify 2 characters in the correct position from a 4 character string

Tags: regex, simplify

For example, I have the String "abcd", and I want all matches to be found in which at least 2 of those characters match, in the correct position. So, ab12, a1c2, 12cd, etc will all match because they contain at least 2 characters in the correct index from abcd.

I realize I could try doing it by /ab..|a.c.|a..d|.bc.|.b.d|..cd/g, but is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this with the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package.

[See code working here](https://tio.run/##LYzLCoMwEEXXzldkNwkWQe1KKn5I6SKNsQbMg5iCpfTb0yHt6tw5M3PDK63e9TkbG3xMLOqHPgB2NjKUdzUjSIpXym2HJ3KtKmw72hX2hXR7/nPGG0Ckr9LVKG@D2TRHPg1Y/5zelQya76JG8daXsfugAFh8ZAczjskBKrPw2CzPbbMyqZUfQpCsQjQu0ZDzFw)

```
import regex

s = 'abcd'
a = ['ab12', 'a1c2', '12cd', '123d', 'abc4', 'abcd']

r = regex.compile('(?:'+regex.escape(s)+'){e<=2}')

for x in a:
    if(r.fullmatch(x)):
        print(x)
```

This uses *fuzzy matching* `{e<=2}` to identify strings that have 2 or fewer *errors* (insertion, substitution, deletion). You can instead specify `{s<=2}` for only substitutions if you'd like.

For list comprehension, you can replace the last three lines with the following:

```
print([x for x in a if(r.fullmatch(x))])
```